# Error: Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt, system.xml

I'm getting the following error when trying to do a transform:

> Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element
>   after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.

Below is the function I'm using to do the transform

```
Public Function Transform(ByVal doc As XmlNode, ByVal stylesheet As XmlDocument) As String
    Dim trans As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
    trans.Load(stylesheet)
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = False
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    settings.CloseOutput = False

    Dim writer As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
    trans.Transform(doc, XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings))

    Return writer.ToString()
End Function
```

Below is the offending code in my xsl

```
<xsl:template name="Calendar">
    <xsl:variable name="dateRef"><xsl:value-of select="@dateRef"/></xsl:variable>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top: 10px">
                        <span style="position:absolute; display:none" fieldName="{//Form/@name}.{Name}" initialDate="{@initialDate}" futureBound="{@futureBound}" pastBound="{@pastBound}">
                            <xsl:attribute name="ID">date<xsl:value-of select="$dateRef"/></xsl:attribute>
                        </span>
                        <!-- When I comment out the line below my page loads, but the intended content doesn't -->
                        <xsl:attribute name="ID">date<xsl:value-of select="$dateRef"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:call-template name="calendarContents"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:** As the error indicates, a "text, comment, pi, or ***sub-element*** node" may not intervene between `xsl:attribute` and the element receiving the attribute.

**Solution:** Move the `xsl:attribute` statement up to be **immediately** beneath the `td` element to which you wish to add the attribute.